# How to keep value updated after button is pressed?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, tableview

I have two view controllers, both with table views.

Depending on which row you select in the first table view, the second table view cell's are filled with the subcategories of the min category you select in the initial table view. In the second table view there is also a button.

I am trying to pass the value of the row selected in the first table view to the button in the table view cell of the second table view in order to use it in the future and to keep track of the row selected in the first table view.

What would be the best way to implement this?

Every time I click the button in the table view cell of the second table view I `print(initialRow)` but it's always 0, how can I change it so it shows the correct value which is the index of the row selected in the first table view?

Here is my code for first table view:

```
import UIKit

var trainingDict = ["Ball Handling" : ["1 Ball Stationary Drills", "1 Ball Combo Moves", "2 Ball Stationary Drills", "2 Ball Combo Moves", "2 Ball Partner Drills", "Handle Hoop Drills", "Placeholder"], "Shooting" : ["Form Shooting", "Spot Shooting", "Off The Dribble Shots", "Pull Up Jumpshots", "Catch & Shoots", "Free Throws", "Partner Shooting"], "Defense" : ["5 Star Drill", "Full Court Def. Slides", "1 v 1 Closeouts", "Gauntlet Drill", "Tennis Ball Reaction Drill", "Lane Slides", "Place Holder"], "Advanced Drills" : ["D Man Series", "Iso Series", "Double Move Series", "Gauntlet Series", "John Wall Drill", "Floater Series", "PlaceHolder"], "Vertimax Drills" : ["One Foot Jumps", "Box Jumps", "Resitance Slides", "Resistance Jumps", "Resistance Ball Handling", "Vertimax Sprints", "Slam Drill"], "Full Workouts" : ["Workout A", "Workout B", "Workout C", "Workout D", "Workout E", "Workout F", "Workout G"], "BHB Products" : ["Handle Hoops", "Handle Cubes", "Strech Bands", "Advocare", "Placeholder", "Placeholder2", "Placeholder3"]]

//gradient creation
var gradient : CAGradientLayer!
var drillLabelGradient : CAGradientLayer!
var myIndex = 0


class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: TableView!

    var trainingCategories = [String]()
    var arrayForKey = Array(trainingDict.values)
    var selectedKey = 0
    var rowIcon = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "bballIcon"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "pullup"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "kidBB"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "girlBB"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "3ball"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "dstance"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "dunk")]

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return rowIcon.count
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "bell") as! ViewControllerTableViewCell

        //cell details
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        //gradient details
        gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = tableView.bounds
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.darkGray.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor]
        tableView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)

        //details what the text label of cell displays
        var trainingCategories = Array(trainingDict.keys)

        myIndex = indexPath.row

        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Symbol", size: 24.0)
        cell.textLabel?.text = trainingCategories[myIndex]
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
        cell.borderColor = UIColor.white
        cell.borderWidth = 1.5
        cell.imageView?.image = rowIcon[myIndex]

        print(trainingCategories.count)

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath.row)
        selectedKey = indexPath.row
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "segue" {
            if let secondTableView = segue.destination as? DrillsViewController {
                //how labels in second table view corresspond to the first table view labels
                secondTableView.keyIndex = selectedKey
                secondTableView.arrayForKey2 = arrayForKey
                secondTableView.initialRow = selectedKey
            }
        }
    }     

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        trainingCategories = Array(trainingDict.keys)
    }
}
```

Code for second table view:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class DrillsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var initialRow = Int()
    var arrayForKey2 = [[String]]()
    var keyIndex = Int()
    var headLabel = String()
    var labels = Array(trainingDict.keys)

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: DrillsTableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var drillLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var labelBackground: UIView!

    @IBAction func back(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "back", sender: self)
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return arrayForKey2.count
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! DrillsTableViewCell
        cell.playButton.tag = indexPath.row

        //clear background color needed in order to display gradient cell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear



        //details for cell label display
        cell.borderWidth = 1.5
        cell.borderColor = UIColor.white
        cell.drillTitle.text = "\(arrayForKey2[keyIndex][indexPath.row])"
        cell.drillTitle.font = UIFont(name: "Symbol", size: 18.0)
        cell.drillTitle.textColor = UIColor.white

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! DrillsTableViewCell
        cell.initialRow = initialRow
        print(cell.initialRow)
        print(indexPath.row)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        drillLabel.text = labels[keyIndex]
    }
}
```

Code for the second table view's table view cell:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class VideoPlayerView: UIView {

    let pauseButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Triangle 2"), for: .normal)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.tintColor = UIColor.white
        button.isHidden = false
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlePause), for: .touchUpInside)

        return button
    }()

    var isPlaying = false

    func handlePause() {
        if isPlaying {
            player?.pause()
            pauseButton.alpha = 1.0
        } else { 
            player?.play()
            pauseButton.alpha = 0.01
        }

        isPlaying = !isPlaying
    }

    //container view that holds sublayers for the video control objects
    let controlsContainerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 1.0)
        return view
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        //configures container view (video's background)
        controlsContainerView.frame = frame
        addSubview(controlsContainerView)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.black

        //following adds pause/play button to video
        controlsContainerView.addSubview(pauseButton)
        pauseButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        pauseButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true    
    }

    var player: AVPlayer?

    //function that sets up video playback
    func setupPlayerView(for url: URL) {
        player = AVPlayer(url: url)

        //video only renders if you specify 'playerLayer'
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        self.layer.insertSublayer(playerLayer, at: 1)
        playerLayer.frame = frame

        player?.play()

        //attached obeserver of 'player' to tell when 'player' is ready
        player?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentItem.loadedTimeRanges", options: .new, context: nil)
    }

    //method called every time you add obserever to an object
    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        //strring that lets AVPlayer know its ready
        if keyPath == "currentItem.loadedTimeRanges" {        
            //configures container view while video is playing
            controlsContainerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            pauseButton.alpha = 0.03
            isPlaying = true        
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }    
}


class DrillsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var videoURL:[URL] = [URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/jordanlagrone/Desktop/BlackHeartBB/BlackHeartBB/dunk.mov"), URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/jordanlagrone/Desktop/BlackHeartBB/BlackHeartBB/mk.MOV")]
    var video = URL(fileURLWithPath: String())
    var initialRow = Int()

    var player: AVPlayer?
    var playerController = AVPlayerViewController()

    @IBOutlet weak var drillTitle: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!
    @IBAction func watchButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print(initialRow)
        print(String(sender.tag))

        //controls video background view
        if let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            let view = UIView(frame: keyWindow.frame)
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            let singleVideoURL = videoURL[sender.tag]

            view.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: keyWindow.frame.width, height: keyWindow.frame.height)

            let videoPlayerFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: keyWindow.frame.width, height: keyWindow.frame.width * 9 / 16)
            let videoPlayerView = VideoPlayerView(frame: videoPlayerFrame)
            videoPlayerView.setupPlayerView(for: singleVideoURL)
            view.addSubview(videoPlayerView)

            keyWindow.addSubview(view)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                view.frame = keyWindow.frame
            }, completion: { (completedAnimation) in
                // possible features implemented later
                UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true
            })            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please reduce the code to the minimum that illustrates your problem. Removing irrelevant parts as view/layout configuration makes understanding your actual question much easier.

Comment: Well I'm trying to pass a value through all the swift files so I would think they are all relevant.

Comment: The shadow offset of an unused button is irrelevant for your problem. Removing all lines of code that is not about passing the reference will help you understand the problem (and solution) better.

Comment: Do you have any insight on my question? Why is `initialRow` being set to zero when I call it in inside the `watchButton` function action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `cellForRow` method in `DrillsViewController`, you dequeue a cell as `DrillsTableViewCell` but never set the `initialRow` attribute of `DrillsTableViewCell`. This means that when the cell is dequeued, the only line that sets the value of `initialRow` in `DrillsTableViewCell` is

```
var initialRow = Int()
```

What you need to do is assign the value of `initialRow` from `DrillsViewController` to `initialRow` from `DrillsTableViewCell` in your `cellForRow` method

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! DrillsTableViewCell
    cell.playButton.tag = indexPath.row

    //clear background color needed in order to display gradient cell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    cell.initialRow = initialRow //THIS IS THE LINE YOU ARE MISSING

    //details for cell label display
    cell.borderWidth = 1.5
    cell.borderColor = UIColor.white
    cell.drillTitle.text = "\(arrayForKey2[keyIndex][indexPath.row])"
    cell.drillTitle.font = UIFont(name: "Symbol", size: 18.0)
    cell.drillTitle.textColor = UIColor.white

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Glad to be of help